# Base image is blank

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, product-images

i hope someone can help me. Base image is not showing when I choose the product, but small and thumbnail works fine.This happened after I imported products again but with the Default attribute (I updated the products with just default attribute). **It´s not even working if I create a product manually and browsing the image.**
I have tried the following things:

- 1- reindex, static content deployment, flush and clean cache, etc...
  2- give permission to pub/media folder

  3. run the command php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
  4. Check that Default attribute is ok and enabled.
  5. Unchecked base image from product and check it again.
  6. check in the db table catalog_product_entity_media_gallery; that the image path was ok.
  7. imported many test products with images in pub/media/import
     There are 2 weird things here:

     1. Only in base image it´s not showing anything, but I can even see the image URL and the image itself if I use inspect element in the area of the base image.
     2. If I add an additional image it shows both, base and additional image in an incorrect size, but I don´t want to add additional images.
        This is how it looks like.
        [image]

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I face same problem. I already done all possible ways to show image like check code and reindex data, delete var,cache,flush, sessions by commands but not getting result. At the last I deleted that products and insert once again. I got surprised that everything works fine. I dont know what is the problem but i know that this step solve my problem.

This may be help you to solve your problem

Comment: Hello, thank you for the idea, I tried that and did not work. But I discovered that my problem was related more with styles, I don´t how but the style for base image was width: 1px, I have changed many styles in my .less file and now i´m able to see the images. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Chirag's solution I would just try to delete and re-upload the picture. That's what worked for me.