# Migrated images not showing frontend and backend both

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, product-images, migration

Hi I have migrated my magento 1.9.2 to 2.3.0 and migrated images manually whole media folder. But for some products images are not showing in frontend  or even in backend. In admin panel product -> product image and video it is showing 0 bytes for images. It is showing the magento placeholder in front-end and back-end.

Please help what is the issue.

Comment: see this link :- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/278160/base-image-is-blank/278249#278249

Comment: Thanks but I have too much products and migrated from magento 1.9

Answer (score 0):

Please run following command.

```
php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: I already tried this but not effect

Comment: on m1 site products page showing this url which is ok : https://adsf.xx/media/product/854/teleasdfda-clx-4-asdfsd-1-3m-d6a.jpg

Comment: but on m2 products page it is showing placeholder

Comment: on single product page img link is : media/product/f9f/telescoopsteel-clx-4-hybride-1-3m-by-gardiner-d6a.jpg - Ok

Comment: So why on m2 it is looking for /pub/media/catalog/product/cache/ed45c8505bfbcd99e44d4a0943ea3745/c/l/clx4_front_1200_1.jpg

I checked there `/c/l` is not existing on both m1 and m2

Comment: why m2 is looking for clx4_front_1200_1.jpg?